# Docker Swarm Error Response

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm, distributed-system

I'm trying to run the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f) to use my chain code on multiple hosts.

After copying this (with PC 1's output of course):

```
docker swarm join — token SWMTKN-1–3as8cvf3yxk8e7zj98954jhjza3w75mngmxh543llgpo0c8k7z-61zyibtaqjjimkqj8p6t9lwgu 172.16.0.153:2377
```

from PC 1 to PC 2, I'm getting an error output like this:

> Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc:
>   the connection is unavailable

I googled this problem, but haven't found a solution to solve my problem yet. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem seems to be with your IP: `172.16.0.153`. Just try to ping this IP from `PC2`. I don't think it'd be available. Also, add the `docker swarm init ... ` command in the question. Did you use `--advertise-addr` flag to specify the IP.

Comment: `PC 1` must be available over the network for `PC 2` to connect it via `swarm join ...` @My_h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is initializing the swarm with the network IP of `PC 1`. If you're on a windows machine, use `ipconfig`; on Linux and MAC use `ifconfig`; to see the IP of the interface you're connected to the network with. Most probably, it would be something like `192.168...`.

You can confirm whether this IP is reachable from `PC 2` by pinging it from `PC 2` using `ping <PC 1 IP>`. If it gives success response, you're good to go to the next step. Otherwise, you used a wrong IP. Try some other interface's IP.

After finding the IP, initialize the swarm using the following commands. Use the IP found above in the second command.

`docker swarm leave --force`

`docker swarm init --advertise-addr <IP address of PC 1>`

Use the output of the last command in `PC 2` and it should get connected to the swarm as a worker with `PC 1` as the manager. 
Before joining swarm on `PC 2`, execute `docker swarm leave --force` just to be safe.

Comment: I could ping PC 1 from PC 2.